# Permission denied after deploy app with capistrano

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have a `deploy.rb`like this

```
set :application, "api"
set :repository,  "git@github.com/org/api.git"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :scm_passphrase, "passwd"

set :scm, :git

set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

role :web, "192.168.0.95"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "192.168.0.95"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "192.168.0.95", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
role :db,  "192.168.0.95"
```

as you can see, I'm doing a deploy to our intranet...
After this, I executed `bundle exec foreman start` on our server and when I access the app, i see this:

```
Permission denied - /var/www/releases/20120719190900/tmp/cache
```

I tried to chmod and chown our www folder, but nothing changed...
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Try chmod and chown on your current /tmp folder instead of releases /tmp folder.

Comment: I did `sudo chown -R user /var/www` with no success. Tried to chown on /tmp folder. same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created the folder `cache` inside `tmp` folder and it worked! Strange thing...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `set :use_sudo, true` instead of false?

Comment: same thing...I've tried to deploy to `/var/rails` instead `/var/www`